# rebuilding/frankenbike query

Tags: frames, bmx

My son (teenager) has a second-hand Zombie bmx style bike - it's designed for kids, but as far as I can see the frame size is the same as any bmx. It needed a bit of messing around with, I've already replaced the wheels, which were fairly nasty pretend mags whose rims deformed whenever the tyres were inflated. What I'm now wondering is - the frame, like a lot of kids' bikes, is bulky and heavy. Is there a any reason why I couldn't transpose everything onto a different frame? Or am I missing an obvious incompatibility?

I love bikes, but as you can probably tell, bmx-s are foreign territory for me!

Comment: Could you add a picture or two and a list of components?

Comment: I suggest working out which parts you actually want to keep. Are the wheels particularly good or something? Otherwise it's almost certainly going to be cheaper and easier just to get a new/second hand bike that already works. If there's a bike recycling group near you they'd be the ones to go to for help..

Answer (score 7):

Unequivocally, yes, you can - it's just a matter of whether or not it's worth it to you.

Without seeing pictures or details: to avoid unnecessary added expense, you'll want to stick with frames that have:

- The same head tube diameter, so you don't have to replace the headset
- The same bottom bracket shell width (usually 68mm or 73mm), so you don't have to replace it and/or the crankset
- The same rear brake mounts, so you don't have to replace that too (V-Brake/Braze-ons lower than the rim, U-Brake/Braze-ons higher than the rim, or cantilever/a hole in the center, disk brakes/two holes on the non-drive side near the hub). However, I'd probably go with V-Brake mounts and replace the rear brake if it has anything but disk.
- The same seat tube diameter, so you can re-use the seatpost and clamp